# Puphpet provisioning fails on installing node

Tags: node.js, puphpet

running the `vagrant up` on a previously functioning infrastructure fails with the following error

```
==> default: Error: Command npm is missing
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Puphpet_nodejs/Package[express]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Command npm is missing
```

Answer (score 2):

Had a look into the responsible script within the VM "/.puphpet-stuff/node_install.sh" and it seems the URL its using to fetch the latest node version is not exists  anymore and thats cause this failure.

I found out the correct URL (perhaps changed recently on nodejs.org website and replaced in the file and it works now.

```
vagrant ssh
sudo vim /.puphpet-stuff/node_install.sh
```

and change

```
http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/SHASUMS.txt
```

To

```
http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/SHASUMS256.txt
```